# How to catch the event of the window close button(red X button on window right top corner) in wpf form?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events

How can I catch the event of the window close button(red X button on window right top corner) in a WPF form? We have got the closing event, window unloaded event also, but we want to show a pop up if he clicks the close button of the WPF form.

Comment: So what happened if you did something in the Closing event, Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `Closing` event in the Window, you can handle it like this to prevent it from closing:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I needed to all the closing handler to the respective window's XAML:
`<Window [...] Closing="myWindow_Closing">`

Comment: Do remember though, that this event also fires when you call `this.Close()` from the code behind.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION:**

***Have a flag*** to identify if Close() method is called from other than X icon button. (eg: IsNonCloseButtonClicked;)

***Have a conditional statement inside Closing ()*** event method which checks if the IsNonCloseButtonClicked is false.

If false, the app is trying to close itself through other than X icon button. If true, it means X icon button is clicked for closing this app.

**[Sample Code]**

```
private void buttonCloseTheApp_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  IsNonCloseButtonClicked = true;
  this.Close (); // this will trigger the Closing () event method
}


private void MainWindow_Closing (object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
  if (IsNonCloseButtonClicked) {
    e.Cancel = !IsValidated ();

    // Non X button clicked - statements
    if (e.Cancel) {
      IsNonCloseButtonClicked = false; // reset the flag
      return;
    }
  } else {

    // X button clicked - statements
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if it is pressed confirm button in form2 do action, if it is pressed X-button do nothing:

```
public class Form2
{
  public bool confirm { get; set; }

    public Form2()
        {
            confirm = false;
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

   private void Confirm_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //your code
       confirm = true;
       this.Close();

    }

}
```

first form:

```
public void Form2_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Form2.confirm == false) return;

            //your code 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET:

```
    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    ' finalize the class

    End Sub
```

To disable the Form X button:

```
'=====================================================
' Disable the X button on the control bar
'=====================================================
Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim myCp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
        Return myCp
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

at *form1.Designer.cs* put below code to assign the event

```
this.Closing += Window_Closing;
```

at *form1.cs* put the closing function

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //change the event to avoid close form
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            string msg = "Close or not?";
            MessageBoxResult result =
              MessageBox.Show(
                msg,
                "Warning",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                // If user doesn't want to close, cancel closure
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        }
```