# handling window close button in wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

is there a way to handle the window close button ie "X" in the top right corner in the viewmodel by binding to a command? or overriding the window.close command so that closing one window goes back to the previous window. Thanx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch the event of the window close button(red X button on window right top corner) in wpf form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969846/how-to-catch-the-event-of-the-window-close-buttonred-x-button-on-window-right-t)

Answer (score 35):

There are several methods for this. I have pointed out two methods below.

1. You can use attached commands to bind the close button in your view model.
2. You can use Below code

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfInfragisticsModal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        Name="myWindow">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> **NOTE: Add System.Windows.Interactivity reference**

View Model

```cs
private ICommand closeWindowCommand;

public ICommand CloseWindowCommand
{
      get
      {
          if (closeWindowCommand == null)
          {
             closeWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.CloseWindow(), null);
          }
          return closeWindowCommand;
      }
 }

private void CloseWindow()
{
     //Do your operations
}
```

This is my RelayCommand class.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RelayCommand"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execute.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RelayCommand"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execute.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The can execute.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Action
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;


    /// <summary>
    /// Predicate
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
}
```

Comment: Exactly like this, MVVM Light can help you out!

Comment: thanx haritha, i tried it but it did not work for me, i couldnt find 'system.windows.interactivity' namespace..i'm using VS2010..some suggested 'windowsbase' but even that did not work to get xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" to work...

Comment: Hi Andris,
You have to install a redistributable to appear that in Visual Studio. 
You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) .

Comment: OK, `Closing` is `Window` event that fires before **window closing**, which is not equal to **X button Click** just because the `Window` can be closed from any place in code by `Window.Close()`. So, if one needs to separate closing window by UI from closing by code (for example - kind of custom InputDialog) - that's pretty hardcore, I don't see any solution for that now.

Comment: There is a nuget package for Expression SDK `Install-Package Expression.Blend.Sdk` just incase someone else ran intro trouble with the missing .dll

Comment: @oxfn: Ex-ACTLY!  IMHO, for all its prolly over-engineered customization options, it's a MAJOR shortcoming for WPF to not have a built-in way to bind to the Window Close *Button* DIRECTLY vs. INDIRECTLY via the `Window.Closing` *Event* the latter of which, as you pointed out, is Raised even when the `Window.Close` Method is called, which would be a problem, if the code (in an, again imho, *very* common scenario) needs to treat the Window Close *Button* the same as a "Cancel" button, but the `Window.Closing` *Event* is also being Raised by the Handler for say an "OK" / "Select" Button.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that i was closing a parent window and reopening it after closing its respective child window, causing memory leaks. I resolved by hiding the parent window and then showing it again after child window closes. I am new to wpf and windows development so i learn as i go.