# How to validate the input field using MVVMPattern when GotFocus event fire?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following **view**

[image]

I have to check TextBox1 is empty or not when TextBox2 is getting focus. If the TextBox one is empty, i have to prompt a message with message box.

Comment: You can use the "LostFocus" event of the TextBox1.

Comment: No code behind. i have to achieve this scenario with MVVM Pattern

Comment: OK. Then you can define a `command` in your `view model` and then bind it to the `event`. Please look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201785/873979)

Comment: @ASHOKA: "No code behind" - please, stop the madness. MVVM doesn't mean "No code behind". Code behind usage isn't a violation of MVVM pattern. In particular, focus management is a *view* responsibility, not a view model.

Answer (score 1):

Handle [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) event for `TextBox2`, find binding expression for `TextBox1.Text` property, and call [`BindingExpression.UpdateSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx).

Note, that you should set `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"` for `TextBox1.Text`, if you want to prevent default validation behavior (when `TextBox1` had lost focus).

**UPD**.

Code sample (with data error validation).
The view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // INPC implementation is omitted

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return text1; }
        set
        {
            if (text1 != value)
            {
                text1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text1");
            }
        }
    }
    private string text1;


    public string Text2
    {
        get { return text2; }
        set
        {
            if (text2 != value)
            {
                text2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text2");
            }
        }
    }
    private string text2;

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (columnName == "Text1" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text1))
                return "Text1 cannot be empty.";

            return null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Name="Text1" Text="{Binding Text1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Text2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingExpression = Text1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer why because i am newbie to mvvm pattern, please give me the code.

Comment: @ASHOKA: see my comment to your question above.

Comment: i assume that it is possible to create attached property to avoid code behind like private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingExpression = Text1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
    }. But i don't know how to implement this so.

Answer (score 1):

ViewModel should provide some validation errors for its properties. see `System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo`. In MVVM it is no problem if view depends on its viewmodel. Code in CodeBehind is not bad per se, it should only be well thought-out.

Comment: I also think that if you're using MVVM you should implement the IDataErrorInfo for fields validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can Hook-up a Command to an event to perform this to a WPF MVVM implemented application. check this [link](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html) man for your reference. Goodluck!