# Binding to Window close event in MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to capture the close event on my view to invoke a save method. I don't want the user to be able to close the window and dispose of un-saved changes. I have tried to use

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()
```

But the view In question is not my `MainWindow`. Is there any way to bind the close window to a command from Xaml along the lines of:

```
public RelayCommand CloseWindow;
Constructor()
{
    CloseWindow = new RelayCommand(CloseWin);
}

public void CloseWin(object obj)
{
    Window win = obj as Window;
    win.Close();
}
```

& the Xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=WindowNameTobeClose}" Content="Cancel" />
```

But capturing the window close event rather than bound to a defined button in the UI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201122/handling-window-close-button-in-wpf-mvvm

Comment: @Sajeetharan, this question is an exact duplicate of your linked question. It would help to clean this site up if you voted to close it for being a duplicate in future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my solution. Namespace in Xaml:

```
xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Xaml binding:

```
 <z:Interaction.Triggers>
        <z:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" />
        </z:EventTrigger>
    </z:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I already had a commands helper class in the project. Here's the exposed property in my viewModel:

```
   private ICommand _CloseArticleCommand;
    public ICommand CloseArticleCommand
    {
        get { return _CloseArticleCommand; }
        set
        {
            _CloseArticleCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CloseArticleCommand");
        }
    }
```

The property is initialized in a viewModel constructor method:

```
  private void InitialiseBtnCommands()
    {
        CloseWindowCommand = new BtnCommand(CloseWindowCommandAction);         
    }
```

And finally the action method which performs the save:

```
 private void CloseWindowCommandAction()
        {
            //Save your data etc.                
        }
```