# VB .Net WPF changing windows

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to create a WPF application with a number of windows and am getting a bit confused with the correct way to do this. I understand that I need to keep the main window open for the program to run, so I hide this for the sub windows. However, the problem occurs when I want to change from one sub window to another and can be narrowed down to the following: how to catch the event when the user presses the close button in the top right (there seems to be no way to reference when this button is pressed in VB .net)?

Currently, I am closing the current window and then creating a new instance of the next window to change from one to the other, like the following:

```
Private Sub btnContinue_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnContinue.Click

    Dim wd As New NextWindow
    Me.Close()
    wd.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

There is an exit button:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

and I have the following in the window closing event:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Show()
```

But how do I differentiate if the exit button is pressed or the continue button or the default close button in the top right of every window? if the exit button or close button is pressed, I would like to close the current window and then show the main window. If the continue button is pressed, I would like to close the current window and then show the next window.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Navigation framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.100).aspx) in WPF to navigate between pages instead?

Comment: I recommend you to use the Prism framework. It manage all this work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the navigation framework or the prism framework to go with these solutions. The navigation framework looks more towards a browser, though it does say it can be used in standalone applications. Prism looks quite meaty and may be for applications bigger than I'm dealing with at the moment. Will definitely look into both at some point. For now, I've settled with just hiding the intermediate windows until the final window is finished with and then closing them all to the main window. Not ideal, but the quickest solution I see at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

I am in the belief that this old question holds your answer:

[How to catch the event of the window close button(red X button on window right top corner) in wpf form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969846/how-to-catch-the-event-of-the-window-close-buttonred-x-button-on-window-right-t)

This shows an event on Window_Closing that may be what you are looking for.

Hope that helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.