# Handle closing event of all windows in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, eventhandler

In WPF for registering an event for all window something like this should written in App class :

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseDown));
```

But `Window` class does not have any property for handling `Closing` event

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969846/how-to-catch-the-event-of-the-window-close-buttonred-x-button-on-window-right-t?

Comment: @user3164323 Actually I'm looking for something which catches closing of all windows not just controls inside one window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window does have a Closing event that you can cancel but it is not RoutedEvent so you cannot subscribe to it in this fashion.

You can always inherit the Window and subscribe to closing in one place. All inheriting Windows will inherit this behavior also.

**EDIT**

This can be done with behaviors as well.
Make sure you install a NuGet package called [Expression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/).
Than create an attached behavior like so:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace testtestz
{
    public class ClosingBehavior : Behavior<Window>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Closing += AssociatedObject_Closing;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Closing -= AssociatedObject_Closing;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Close the window?", AssociatedObject.Title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
}
```

Than in your XAML add this behavior like so:

```
<Window x:Class="testtestz.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testtestz"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ClosingBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Although inheritance seems a descend way but I hate to do so for visualized classes (Like Window, button and so) cause overhead of inheritance can be sensed in UX specially when user does not have a normal GPU

Comment: I hate this too since visual inheritance does not exist in XAML. The only other thing I can think of is an attached behavior that you would attach to every Window.

Answer (score 0):

What about registering to the Unloaded event? which has it's own property. For example:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseDown));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), UnloadedEvent, new RoutedEventArgs( ... ));
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use unload event because I want to cancel close in closing event